Sorting objects by key matching a specific sequence
I have a sequence of structs, say
struct Foo
{
    std::string key;
    int value;
};

The data points represented by these structs can arrive in any order, but need to go out in a specific order. I would represent that order by a sequence of keys, like so:
const std::vector<std::string> keySequence = {"thisMustBeFirst", "thenThisOne", "andThenThatOne"};

Now given a std::vector<Foo> and my hardcoded key sequence, I want to arrange my input data so that each object is at the position of its key in the required sequence. Precondition guarantees that all keys actually exist in the input, so the sorting is my only concern here.
My first plan was std::sort but it kinda feels like this might be the wrong approach, because I can't find an immediately obvious comparison function to give it. Am I maybe thinking about this the wrong way?
There are no hard requirements about the data structures, so maybe there's a different design that works better here?
I'd appreciate any and all suggestions.

A trivial less-than comparator for std::sort would return true if the index of key-a in keySequence is smaller that the index of key-b in keySequence. However if you have a lot of entries in keySequence this will not be efficient. To improve it you can build a map of key to index.

You describe HOW you want to solve something, but WHAT is the actual requirement of your data structure? Should lookup be fast, do you only want the output (or iteration) to have this sort order. Does insertion need to be fast, or retrieval? I've done a lot of datastructures and the internal storage depends most on those requirements.

@PepijnKramer It's not a performance-critical operation, the upper bound for data points is around 1000 and the transformation is between two network IO operations. So the only requirement is to output in the defined key sequence order.

@wohlstad Your comment gave me exactly the tiny little push I needed to see the forest beyond all the trees. Thanks! If you wanna make it an answer, I'll accept it.

@Io-asys good to know, posted as an answer.

Is the mapping 1-to-1 or does the same key appear multiple times?

You can implement the following less-than comparator for std::sort:

Find the index of the first key in keySequence, let's call it index1.
Find the index of the second key in keySequence, let's call it index2.
Return index1 < index2.

Note:
If keySequence is long, searching through it to get the index of the key might hurt your performance.
In this case you can first build a map from key to index, and use it in stages 1 and 2 above.
Gegarding which map to use: 2 obvious options are std::map and std::unordered_map. Each has its advantages and disadvatages and choosing between them should be done based on profiling.

You don't need to sort. You can solve this with an unordered_map in O(n) time. The trick is to enable lookup of the Foo objects by their key values. Then you can simply iterate through your keySequence and search the corresponding Foo entry.
  const std::vector<std::string> keySequence = {
    "thisMustBeFirst", "thenThisOne", "andThenThatOne"};
  const std::vector<Foo> sequence = {
    { "thenThisOne", 1 },
    { "andThenThatOne", 2 },
    { "thisMustBeFirst", 3 } };

  using key_map_t = std::unordered_map<std::string_view, const Foo*>;
  key_map_t keyMap;
  for(const Foo& foo: sequence)
    keyMap[foo.key] = &foo;
  for(const std::string& key: keySequence) {
    const Foo* foo = keyMap[key];
    ...
  }


if I understood correctly the keys can appear multiple times in the main sequence (i.e. the main sequence can be longer than keySequence). Maybe the OP can clarify.

@wohlstad good point. In that case, it becomes an std::unordered_multimap or unordered_map<string_view, vector<Foo*>>

Yes that is a possible solution. But in case the OP would like to sort the original sequnce it is possible as well as I showed in my answer.

For clarification: The keys can not appear more than once in the input; the input can contain keys that are not in the sequence, but those are filtered out in a separate step. This is a pretty clever solution, I'll definitely consider going this way if the O(n²) version turns out to be too slow.

@Io-asys sorry for pedanrty, but its not just "clarification" but basically a different problem. If keys appear only once in the input you should mention that in the quesiton (did I miss it?). In that case you dont have to "sort" the input but merely populate a vector of ints that is parallel to the vector of keys

You could use a std::multiset<std::string,value> instead of the vector. This requires to establish the order among the std::string keys just as the other solutions suggested so far so I don't expect it to differ substantially in performance for inserting elements, but how you are going to access the data later might make a difference (eg retrieving all element for the same key is easier in a multimap).
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

const std::vector<std::string> keySequence = {"thisMustBeFirst", "thenThisOne", "andThenThatOne"};

struct Foo
{
    std::string key;
    int value;
};


int main() {
    std::multimap<std::string,int,decltype([](auto a,auto b){
        return std::find(keySequence.begin(),keySequence.end(),a) < std::find(keySequence.begin(),keySequence.end(),b); })> m;
    std::vector<Foo> input{{"andThenThatOne",1},{"andThenThatOne",2},{"thisMustBeFirst",3}};
    for (const auto& i : input) {
        m.insert({i.key,i.value});
    }
    for (const auto& x : m) {
        std::cout << x.first << " " << x.second << "\n";
    }
}

Output:
thisMustBeFirst 3
andThenThatOne 1
andThenThatOne 2

